# How to un-ignore certain globs when explorer.excludeGitIgnore is true in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, gitignore

VSCode has a setting to parse and exclude gitignored files from the explorer and search: `explorer.excludeGitIgnore`. Generally this is ok, but sometimes I want an untracked file to show up so it can easily be edited (ex. a `.env` file).

Is there a way to not ignore a set of files via glob when this setting is set?

Ex. `ignore_me_1` will still show in the explorer but `ignore_me_2` will not.

```
# gitignore
ignore_me_1
ignore_me_2
...
```

```json
// vscode settings
{
  "explorer.excludeGitIgnore": true,
  "files.exclude": { "!ignore_me_1": true },
  ...
}
```

Without support for something like this using the `explorer.excludeGitIgnore` setting could lead to issues with file access. If there is not solution here I will open a feature request in the VSCode repo instead.

Comment: what if you prefix with `!**/` instead of just `!`?

Comment: @starball no change unfortunately.

Comment: It appears glob negation is not supported: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/869 and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/134415.